# SQL Server Database Roles via SMO

Tags: sql-server, database, roles, smo

I am trying to add new roles to a SQL 2005 database via the SMO assemblies. The Roles.Add method just does not seem to add the new role. I have my user account set as securityadmin and sysadmin.

Below is the code extract that I am trying to use to set the new role:
[assuming d has been set to a database object]

```
        Dim dr As New DatabaseRole
        dr.Name = r
        dr.Parent = d
        dr.Owner = d.Name
        d.Roles.Add(dr)

        'Error here "<role name = r> does not exist in the current database."'
        dr.AddMember("dbo")
```

Comment: It's not really an answer, but you can create roles without DMO.  SSMS allows you to add a role and then generate an SQL script for it.  You can fire that script from code, instead of using DMO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create the role and then assign it to the database.

Change your code to:

```
Dim dr As New DatabaseRole        
dr.Name = r        
dr.Parent = d        
dr.Owner = d.Name  
dr.Create();      
d.Roles.Add(dr)        
dr.AddMember("dbo")
```